# Why does Excel Calculated Field only partially work when using days and dates?

Tags: excel, date, calculated-field

I have created a calculated field in my pivot table to show days elapsed from a specific date.
(db column heading is "Assigned Date" which can be blank or any date in the past, formatted as a date)

- Calculated Field contains the formula `=Date(2023,03,10)-'Assigned Date'`
- Value Field Setting:  Summarize value field by: MAX
  Format of resulting field = General or Number (with comma, to 0 decimal places).

For the most part, this formula works beautifully but occasionally, the results do not make sense.
Example:

| Item | Assign Date | Days Assigned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5/18/2022 | 296 |
| B | 6/14/2022 | 269 |
| C | 8/25/2022 | -44,601 |

What could be causing the Calculated Field formula to return such a goofy number for Item C?  If I put the same formula outside the pivot table, it returns the appropriate number (197).

(The first formula I used in the calculated field was the numerical value for today's date (44995 for 3/10/2023), but it had the same result).

Comment: Make sure the cell stored the date as a date and not as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following:

Item C was grouped by the name "Item C" which actually represented 2 records. Record 1: Assigned Date 8/25/2022; Record 2: Assigned Date 8/25/2022.  It appears the calculated field only works in this case when there is only one record per Item.  When there are multiple records, it defaults to returning no date (blank), resulting in the goofy result.

However, if I further split out Item C into its individual records, the calculated field works properly for all lines.

Follow up Question:  How can I set the pivot table to do what I originally wanted? I don't think the Calculated Field window will allow for multi-step formulas (first find the max date of specified parameters, then perform the calculated field step)... does it?

I don't want to see all the individual records of Item C; I'd rather have it grouped... Any ideas?

Comment: Re "*It appears the calculated field only works in this case when there is only one record per Item*", not true. Calculated Fields work at the aggregate level also; yet they **always sum** (no matter what aggregation you set) the values in the fields before then passing these summations to the Calculated Field formula. The result of `-44,601` you see is obtained via `Date(2023,03,10)-(8/25/2022+8/25/2022)`. I might be able to help you if you were to post some raw sample data (not the actual Pivot Table data) with expected result.

Comment: *"Follow up Question"*: the answer section is not intended for new questions.